# Is it possible to understand when a WPF window or page controlls loading is complete?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, xbap

I am working on a WPF Browser Application. I want to know how I can understand when the loading of a page is finished and the components are shown to start loading the heavy background services. Otherwise I just see a white page for some seconds untill all the services are loaded... Any recommendations to solve this problem?

Here is the thing I have tried:

```
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Just some heavy process in the begining
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
                j=j * 2;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("ready");
    }
```

However, the page components don't get loaded in the page untill the processes in page_loaded is finished. Without having the heavy process in the page_loaded, every thing loads very quickly, so there is not any problem in UI.

UPDATE: The thing I understood from loaded event for page or window is that it gets triggered when the page or window gets loaded, and loading of the components and the controlls on the page even the style of it will occure after that... and I don't seem to find any event that shows the loading of the controlls is completed...

UPDATE2: A better solution for my problem is to use BackgroundWorker or the Dispatcher to run the heavy process on background. As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690699/how-to-display-a-wpf-page-or-window-without-waiting-for-heavy-processes-to-finis) post.

Comment: You can listen to the `Loaded` event of the `Window`, `Page` or `UserControl`.

Comment: Guillaume post your comment as an aswer I should say...

Comment: @YoupTube, Tudor did it for me!

Comment: your question heading and question explanation is different. It seems that you want to display the page without waiting for the processes to be completed and also get a notification when the heavy processes are completed. am i right ?

Comment: @DJ, well, I don't need a notification when the heavy process is finished. I need to know when my page and controls inside it have been loaded completely, and then start loading some heavy stuff(initializing kinect, etc). This is for avoiding seeing a white page in the begining...

Comment: @DJ, about displaying the page without waiting for the processes to be completed, how should I do that... Maybe my approach is wrong...

Comment: @DJ you are right. I couldn't use BackgroundWorker since I had to change some Dependency properties in the process, but Dispatcher did the trick... You can add your comment to the answers since it is the correct one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement threading in your application for this. if you write any code in page load method. Your page will not rendered until the load method is completely executed. so you can use [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and run the processes in background

Answer (score 2):

The `Window` class offers the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event:

> Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

Hook up a handler and execute your code there:

```
<Window ... Loaded="Window_Loaded"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it didn't work I it seems... Is there any event that shows that the loading is completed?

Comment: @Mahsa Teimourikia: According to the docs when loaded is fired the loading is fully completed and all controls are initialized. What is happening in your case?

Comment: For me, the page components don't get initialized untill every process in page_loaded is finished...

Comment: @MahsaTeimourikia how can you say that your controls are not initialized?

Comment: By not initialized I meant that they don't get loaded on the page and I don't see them...

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment on your question and as per Tudor's answer, you need to use the `Loaded` event on your `Page`.

```
<Page ... Loaded="Page_Loaded_1"/>
```

Now it seems from your different comments that your Kinect initialisation is done as part of your `Page` UI rendering. Or that some other time-consuming task is being processed.

I have strictly no clue how Kinect works but I suspect in your code its initialization is called from one of the controls you added on the `Page` from Visual Studio Designer.

For example something like that:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding MyKinnectStuff}"/>
```

It may be more subtile. For example using a databinding on a property which getter calls a method initialising your Kinect thing. Double check it's not the case.

From the code sample you added in your edit, be sure that everything related to Kinect (initialisation, databinding, etc) is located in the method `Page_Loaded_1` and that nothing is done directly from within the UI. Also ensure that you don't have any other time-consuming task performed in the UI. Finally, once again, ensure in your XAML you have `<Page Loaded="Page_Loaded_1"/>` and not `<Page Loaded="Something_Else"/>`.

You should edit again your question and show us what your XAML looks like.

Comment: I tried setting a timer in page_loaded and before the timer starts and after the timer finishes show a message to understand when this page_loaded get executed, and both messages pop up when the components are not loaded yet... The Kinect initialization doesn't have anything to do with the UI Components, and page_loaded event is referenced correctly...

Comment: You need to show more code to get more help. What does the XAML look like? Where, when and how the Kinect initialization is done? What are the different interactions between your different components? Otherwise, we can only provide guesses and approximations.

Comment: I removed all the kinect complications, now there is a very simple ui with some buttons, no data binding, and it loads very quickly, but when I add a very long for loop (just to have a long process) in page loaded, nothing gets loaded untill the process is finished...