# How to display a WPF page or window without waiting for heavy processes to finish

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xbap

I am working on a WPF Browser Application. The problem is that I have to load some heavy services in the beginig, this causes to see a white page for some seconds before the page components get loaded. Is there a way to avoid this somehow by loading the page without waiting for the heavy processes to finish?

Here is the thing I am trying now, and it didn't work:

```
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize and configure kinect
        // This takes some seconds
    }
```

I was thinking the page_loaded event happens after all the components of the page have finished loading. But still it waits for the processes to finish and I get some seconds of a white page in the begining...

Comment: Multithreading is about your only choice - search for that.  I don't have time to come up with a full-blown answer, but that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BackgroundWorkers to handle the long-running operations.  This will keep the UI responsive while the task(s) are running.  Go here to learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Could use BackGroundWorker and could call it in either event.
You cannot build or load a UI control in the background.
Build the data and (non UI) objects in the background and then bind on callback.

[BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)